# How can I resize the height of two listviews with respect to one another within a windows form. without resizing the winform itself

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a windows form with two ListViews, one on top of the other. I need a way to be able to resize the height of the top ListView and as the height of the top ListView gets bigger the height of the bottom ListView gets smaller. Without resizing the windows form itself. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps docking the two `ListView` controls in the upper and lower panels of a `SplitContainer`?

Comment: Thank you. SplitContainer is what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I'll post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the outcome you want using `SplitContainer` with `Orientation=Horizontal`.

---

Add the SplitContainer to the `MainForm` and dock it.

[image: add split container]

---

Add ListViews and dock them.

[image: add ListViews]

---

**TEST**

*Class for ListViewItem*

```
// Class for ListViewItem
public class Employee
{
    public static implicit operator ListViewItem(Employee employee)
    {
        return new ListViewItem(new[] { employee.First, employee.Last });
    }
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
}
```

---

*Initialization*

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        listViewTop.View = View.Details;
        listViewBottom.View = View.Details;

        listViewTop.Columns.Add(nameof(Employee.First), 200);
        listViewTop.Columns.Add(nameof(Employee.Last), 200);

        listViewBottom.Columns.Add(nameof(Employee.First), 200);
        listViewBottom.Columns.Add(nameof(Employee.Last), 200);

        listViewTop.Items.Add(new Employee{ First = "Tom", Last = "Cruise", });
        listViewTop.Items.Add(new Employee{ First = "Tom", Last = "Holland", });
        listViewBottom.Items.Add(new Employee{ First = "Tom", Last = "Hanks", });
    }
}
```

---

**Screenshot**

*Now the two `ListView` objects size in coordination with each other by dragging the `Splitter`.*

[image: screenshot]